# How to make KDE Applications appear in the Ubuntu 17.10 Frequent Applications view?

Tags: gnome-shell, kde-apps

Some KDE applications, such as Kolourpaint, KRename, and Kdenlive, do not appear in the Frequent Applications view in Ubuntu 17.10. (I am referring to the frequent applications "dash" accessed by clicking the grid icon in the Ubuntu Dock in gnome-shell).

Other KDE applications like Krita do show up, after they have been used.

How can I get all KDE applications to appear in the Frequent Applications view, if the applications are used often?

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the `StartupWMClass` parameter to the `*.desktop` launcher for affected applications solves the issue.

The value for the `StartupWMClass` parameter should be the application command, found in the `Exec=` line of the `*.desktop` file.

You can do this using `sudo gedit`, or directly from the command line.

For the three applications I listed in my question, the commands would be:

- KRename

  ```
  echo "StartupWMClass=krename" | sudo tee --append /usr/share/applications/kde4/krename.desktop
  ```
- Kdenlive

  ```
  echo "StartupWMClass=kdenlive" | sudo tee --append /usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdenlive.desktop
  ```
- KolourPaint

  ```
  echo "StartupWMClass=kolourpaint" | sudo tee --append /usr/share/applications/org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop
  ```

Note that after doing this, you can not launch *additional* instances of the an application by simply clicking on its icon in the Frequent Applications view or the Applications View in Gnome Shell.  Instead, you need to right-click on the icon, and explicitly select "New Window".  I think this is fine, since this is how other applications in Gnome Shell behave.